# Is there a reason to use std::int64_t from <cstdint>/<cinttypes> over int64_t from <stdint.h>/<inttypes.h>?

Tags: c++

In C++11 we are provided with fixed-width integer types, such as `std::int32_t` and `std::int64_t`, which are defined in cstdint/cinttypes. However, `int32_t` and `int64_t` are also in stdint.h/inttypes.h. What are the reasons to use `std::int64_t` over `int64_t`? To me, the former involves more typing, even by `using namespace std`.

Comment: The purpose of `<cinttypes>` is to provide the printf/scanf macros (and the type `imaxdiv_t`). If you just need the type aliases themselves (and not also `std::div`), use `<cstdint>`.

Comment: You should stay away from `using namespace std;` anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, the "C library" headers of the form `<foo.h>` are deprecated, and headers `<cfoo>` should be used instead. (I put "C library" in quotes because that's just a name for this part of the C++ standard library. Everything we're talking about is part of the C++ standard library, nothing has actually to do with C.)

Whether you should use the non-deprecated headers depends on your personal attitude towards deprecation.

(The amount of physical typing the code author has to do is a *very* poor concern. Code is *read* and *maintained* far more than it is written. The latter are important concerns, the former mostly a distraction.)

Comment: This stupid `std::` before every int64_t makes code a bit less readable.

Comment: @stgatilov: maybe, maybe not. It's not a very long prefix, and it is well known. To me, it signals "this is a standard library type, not some custom idiosyncrasy", which is somewhat reassuring. I like the rule that names from the standard library live in `std`. That's nice and simple, much easier than if I had a series of exceptions to remember.

Comment: you can always do `using std::int64_t` in your namespace in a header like `mylib/common.h` or `mylib/defs.h`.

Comment: Do you have sources about deprecation?